# Git Push hangs up unexpectedly. RPC Failed. Error in HTTP2 framing layer

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, http2

Been getting this error since the last 5-6 hours trying to push a 138kb commit to a repository hosted on Google Cloud.

I have been pushing to this repo for a long time now but just got this error today.

```
error: RPC failed; http2 499 curl 16
fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly.
fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly.
```

I have tried the following:

1. Increasing the http.postBuffer to 1 GB
2. Run the garbage collection
3. Remove the remote origin & re-add it

I cannot use ssh for git. It does not allow me to clone (permission denied).

499: Client Closed Request: I suspect it is timing out.

I am using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4
Git version 2.26.2

Git push freezes after the following output:

```
Enumerating objects: 61, done.
Counting objects: 100% (61/61), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41/41), 138.25 KiB | 15.36 MiB/s, done.
Total 41 (delta 27), reused 18 (delta 10), pack-reused 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SOLUTION]

So, I solved it by resetting and using the [Git Large File Storage Extension](https://git-lfs.github.com/) - [Article](https://medium.com/@AyunasCode/how-to-push-large-files-to-github-253d05cc6a09) on how to use it

Steps I took to resolve:

1. Perform a soft reset to the commit before HEAD (`git reset --soft HEAD~3`)
2. Delete the file and commit the rest of the changes
3. Start tracking .jpg files using the lfs extension `git lfs track ".jpg"`
4. Add the file
5. Commit & push

BOOM! It worked. I have officially spent 8 hours on this problem. Hope this helps someone else who faces this kind of a problem.

Usually, such RPC errors have something to do with a large file (chunk) in your commit. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but it was not caused by a file being too big.
Resetting back to the master's HEAD with `git reset --soft HEAD~2`
and just commiting everything again solved the problem.

Thanks to Varun Joshi.